# How to create rectangle, drag its corners by mouse to create quadrangle, and fill it with image

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, transformation

I have a friend, who is going to build a website, and the need is this:

He wants users to be able to draw quadrangle (no matter, point by point or creating rectagnel and then transform each corner by dragging) and then fill it with any image. Image must contain the same transformation that was got by drawing quadrangle.

Is it possible on HTML5? Maybe some JS with libraries?

Thank you for any help.

NB: This is an [example](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-pxpBjwuM6-Q/UTSmsHNS7YI/AAAAAAAABlM/PsoNEnvlo74/w497-h373/image-transformation.jpg) of what i am talking about..

PS - solution found - http://www.html5.jp/test/perspective_canvas/demo1_en.html

Comment: And what kind of help you want to get? That we just answer the questions you've asked? (Yes, it is possible and no he don't need libraries) ...or that we create for you what he wants to accomplish?

Comment: I just want some examples if they're exist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. And yes, you will need to use some JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good place to start (near the end of page):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

It's a little unclear what he's exactly trying to do. I'm not aware of any way to crop or modify (make actual changes to) an image with only HTML5 and Javascript. But for display purposes only, you can use HTML5 and JS to make it -look- different on the website.

Comment: Thank you, i know basics for HTML5 Canvas, but it's not basics.

Comment: I use ImageMagick to save/modify images. I'm not aware of any javascript libraries that do that kind of image processing.

Comment: Thank you for ImageMagick - by searching it i found the answer: http://www.html5.jp/test/perspective_canvas/demo1_en.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of https://github.com/edankwan/PerspectiveTransform.js . I think this is just what you need

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [projective transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_transformation).

[image]

> Points A, B, C, D and A', B', C', D' are related by a perspectivity, which is a projective transformation.

Martin von Gagern has answered this already with a great explanation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/332080

Basically you'll just need these helper functions and a little time to read what Martin already wrote:

- `Mat3#transform`
- `Mat3#adjugate`
- `Mat3#multiply`